Why does the PyTorch framework become less efficient after using JIT code?
I wanted to optimize the efficiency of my model using PyTorch JIT, but I found that the time after optimization became longer.How can I change it? The question is what?
code    np_output0 = []
for output in rst_list:
    np_output0.append(output.numpy())

traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, [dummy_input], strict=False)
traced_model.eval()

start_time = time.time()  # 记录开始时间
with torch.no_grad():
    rst_list = traced_model(dummy_input)
end_time = time.time()  # 记录结束时间
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time  # 计算执行时间
print(f"JIT Execution time: {elapsed_time} seconds")

enter image description here
